# Limechat hotkey for switching between servers?

Tags: macos, irc

I know that you can do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc to switch between channel 1, channel 2, etc of a particular server that you are currently on. If you have multiple servers that you are connected to, is there any shortcut to switch between the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>1...0</kbd> to switch between servers while using Limechat.

**Example:** Use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to switch to server 5.

Source: [Limechat's homepage.](http://limechat.net/mac/)